# application installer

Tags: linux

how to create installer of application( .sh and .pl files)  on ubuntu? and how to install it?

Answer (score 0):

We need more details to give you a proper answer. However, if you're looking for something installable on a GNU/Linux distribution, I'd recommend you package your application as an [RPM](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) or a [DEB](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html).

On the other hand, if you simply want to create a self extracting "installer", you can consider using [makeself](http://www.megastep.org/makeself/).

I don't know about any perl tool that does this.

Comment: If any of the these answers are helpful to you, you should upvote or accept them.

Comment: not able to install rpm-build package on ubuntu. it give error package not available.  root@smita-desktop:~# apt-get install rpm-build
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package rpm-build

Comment: That's not the name of the package. Do an `apt-cache search rpm build` or search for it on packages.debian.org.

Comment: thank's. i have install alien package which convert rpm file to .deb file. now my requirement is create package of application so that i can install it using yum command.http://lincgeek.org/blog/?p=303 i am trying to create installer using  step given in this link. but really confuse how to do this. so i am trying to create rpm package and then convert it into .deb for installation. is it right or wrong?

Comment: is it any other way to do this without using rpm-builder ?

Comment: i am really sorry. i am ubuntu user. i have one application containing .sh and .pl file. i want to install this application on multiple pc .how can i do this? like in window  we create .exe of application and add it to startup. but here i want to install myapplication using yum.

Comment: yum is part of the Fedora rather that the Debian ecosystem. This thread doesn't seem to be going anywhere and I don't have any more time to spend on this question. You should read http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and ask questions that respect other peoples time. I'm done here.

Answer (score 0):

For linux/unix platform I used InstallAnywhere and InstallShield Universal. Both allows to create projects which can be built for various platforms including win and mac and for linux platforms it creates .bin package which can be installed rather with UI or console mode.